# Why is java not able to infer types for functional interfaces, but still work for regular statements?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I'm working a bit with functional interfaces in java, and right now im trying to define a longfunction that does something simple, like adding numbers or whatever.

However if i try to do this while giving Integer as the type for the longfunction, like this:

```
LongFunction<Integer> i = (l) -> l + l;
```

However this does not work, my compiler complains and say "Bad return type in lambda expression: long cannot be converted to Integer". This would make sense if long's were generally not able to be converted to integers.

But I am perfectly able to do this:

```
    int a = 1;
    int b = 5;
    long l = a +b;
```

Why is this? why is java perfectly able to convert long's to int's and the other way around normally, but in a lambda is so much more rigid?

Comment: You can automatically convert ints to longs, but you can't automatically convert longs to ints because this can cause data loss.

Comment: What makes you think Java is converting longs to ints in your second snippet when `a` and `b` are clearly declared as `int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why is java perfectly able to convert long's to int's and the other
> way around ...

It's not.  It will convert `int` to `long`, which is what your second snippet shows.  It will not do the reverse.

This will generate a compiler error:

```
    long a = 1;
    long b = 5;
    int l = a +b;
```

Since not all `long` values can be stored in an `int`, conversion in this direction is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is converting an integer to a long which is a widening operation and does not result in lost information. So there is not a problem. Going from a long to an int may result in lost information so it would need a cast.

```
interface MyBiFunction<R,S,T>{
        public T apply(R a, S b);
}
```

The following works just fine for both ints and longs even though the return type is a long.

```
MyBiFunction<Integer, Long, Long> fnc1 = (a,b)-> a * b;
long intresult1 = fnc1.apply(10,20L);
long longresult1 = fnc1.apply(10,20l);
```

But this won't since it would be a narrowing operation inside the lambda before it is converted to a long for the final result.

```
MyBiFunction<Integer, Long, Integer> fnc2 = (a,b)-> a * b;
long longresult2 = fnc2.apply(10,20l);

which is the same as 

int a = 10; // ok
long b = 20L; //ok
int v = a*b; //  problem  long*int = long.  Can't assign to int without cast
long longresult2 = v; //ok
```